# Why does the three.js SVGLoader render svgs upside down?

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I've been using the `group.scale.y = -1;` trick on groups to render my svgs in three.js the right way up.

However this messes with the concept of the y coordinate displaying positive values up from the center of my group. Usually the positive y coordinates on the paths would push the svg drawing up (much like the positive x coordinate still pushes to the right) but the scale flip trick to correct the upside down svg also flips the direction by which the y coordinate places the svg. Hence a greater positive y value places the svg further towards the bottom of the canvas.

Can anyone explain why the svgs are rendered upside to begin with and perhaps explain how to fix this so my y coordinates still behave as expected?

Comment: `geometry.rotateZ( Math.PI )`

Comment: I can't use that either. It achieves the same effect as the scale flip. It's really important the svg be rendered the right way up as I need to rely on the x and y coordinates being rendered using the bottom left of the screen. The original svg does this and I cannot place the svg in the same place on my canvas if it is rotated like that since the rendering point is also rotated.

Comment: Your suggestion causes the svg to rotate but does not fix the fact that it is facing the wrong way. I believe this is why the scale.y = -1 flip is used in the svgLoader example on line 145: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_svg.html

Comment: The svg is mirrored along the x axis when rendered so it is literally rendered upside down. Rotating through the z axis means the svg is now back to front. Rotating along the x axis produces the image as it should be rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested in this the reason that SVGs are rendered upside down in Three.js is due to the point from which they are rendered.

In SVGs it appears that while the X axis has positive values it draws further to the right and while the Y axis has positive values it draws further down. This is calculated from the top left point of the image.

In Three.js you have the ability to move left of center (X:0, Y:0) and below center. This is achieved via negative values. In Three.js the canvas asserts that positive Y values move up and negative Y values move down.

As the Renderer draws paths/shapes it uses the original Y value from the SVG which will usually be a positive number causing the drawing coordinate to move up instead of down (like it would usually do in an SVG) which has the effect of drawing your SVG upside down.

Answer (score 2):

In the SVG loader example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_svg.html

You could also flip the actual geometry, not the group scale. This way the object and or group maintain consistent scale information.

```
for ( var j = 0; j < shapes.length; j ++ ) {
    var shape = shapes[ j ];
    var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );
    geometry.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale ( 1, -1, 1 )) // <-- this
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    group.add( mesh );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions is to change the camera angle, this will preserve the geometry and positions.

```
camera.up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
```